# Custom Attributes and enumerators

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, enums, custom-attributes

I have an enum:

```
public enum Navigation
{
    Top = 0,
    Left = 2,
    Footer = 3
}
```

And i have a controller action:

```
public ActionResult Quotes()
{
    return View();
}
```

I would like to be able to decorate my action as follow:

```
[Navigation.Top]
public ActionResult Quotes()
{
    return View();
}
```

Any idea how this could be accomplished, i will probably have to create a custom attribute, but how do i incorporate this enum into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach:

```
public static class Navigation{
  public class Top:ActionFilter /*any attribute*/{
   //magic
  }
  public class Left:ActionFilter{
   //magic
  }
}

[Navigation.Top]
public ActionResult Whatever(){}
```

If You do want to use enums, I'm afraid You won't be able to use them as attributes. But You can pass it to attribute as an argument. Something like this:

```
public class NavigationAttribute:Attribute{
  public Navigation Place {get;set;}
}

[Navigation(Place=Navigation.Top)]
public ActionResult Whatever(){}
```

Comment: Insane... i was doing more or less the same, however, i did not inherit from ActionFilterAttribute.... THANX for the help, this is exactly what i needed

Answer (score 1):

Attribute annotations can only be created with classes derived from `System.Attribute` class.

So, it is not possible to use `enum` directly.

However it is possible to pass your enum value to the constructor of custom attribute. Like this:

```
enum Navigation 
{
    Top = 0,
    Left = 2,
    Footer = 3,
}
class NavigationAttribute: Attribute
{
    Navigation _nav;
    public NavigationAttribute(Navigation navigation){
        _nav = navigation;
    }
}
...
[Navigation(Navigation.Top)]
public ActionResult Quotes()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: thanx, this is also a neat work around. and i suppose that if you are using the enum elsewhere it makes more sense to do it this way.